# using celery in two website with same rabbitmq

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am not much sure about this. In my VPS I have a site running which uses celery and rabbitmq for queuing the task and it is working fine . Now I want to deploy another site in the same server that also uses celery for task. So is it possible that I can use same rabbitmq server for the purpose. I am not sure about this . I need advice

Comment: Yes, you can use as you trying.

Comment: Without details about your environment, configuration, available and used resources, typical load, etc. answers to this questions will be mostly primarily opinion-based.